# socket.io listen / listening event

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am surprised looking at the `socket.io` docs that there is no event that is fired by socket.io when it is bound to a port...I am looking for a "listen" / "listening" event...

http://socket.io/docs/server-api/

I have this simple module that is initialized with a http.Server instance:

```
var io = require('socket.io');

var socketServer = null;

function getSocketServer(httpServer) {

    if (socketServer === null) {

        if (httpServer == null) {
            throw new Error('need to init socketServer with http.Server instance');
        }

        socketServer = io.listen(httpServer);
    }

    return socketServer;

}


module.exports = {
    getSocketServer:getSocketServer
};
```

when I require this module, I want to listen for a 'listening' event.

Something like:

```
var socket = require('./socket-cnx').getSocketServer();

socket.on('listening',function(err){

});
```

I suppose the primary reason is because the `on` API is used for event names.

Comment: Why would you listen for an "igniteEngine" event on a space shuttle that's already in orbit?  Considering the `socket` in your example is the *result of calling io.listen()*, I think it's safe to assume it's already listening.

Comment: @mcmillan that doesnt make sense...http.Server has a listen function and on('listening') event...

Comment: @mcmillan, in the engineering world I am pretty sure if you fire the "ignite-engine" call, listening for an "engine is ignited" event is never superfluous. There is always an error that can happen somewhere and the earlier you catch it the better...you can see some info from Peter Lyons below which probably will answer some questions

Comment: Yes, but `getSocketServer()` is not returning an `http.Server`, is it?

Comment: it is returning that yeah...Lyon's answer is correct

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So socket.io itself doesn't listen. The http server listens, and that's the object that will emit the `listening` event.

If you allow socket.io to create the http server instance for you, that instance is published as the [httpServer property of your io instance](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/2a91fd57c716a350493072cc457de17ebc1b801e/lib/index.js#L234) so you should be able to do `io.httpServer.on('listening', myOnListeningHandler)`

Here's a working sample program:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(4001)

io.httpServer.on('listening', function () {
  console.log('listening on port', io.httpServer.address().port)
})
```

Comment: ok thanks, but what if I use require('socket.io')(4000), where port 4000 is not the same port as my http server? Then how can I listen for that listening event? I do realize that the code I just mentioned creates a new http.Server instance, but then how can I listen to that new server's events? right?

Comment: Answer updated to address that case with link to source code.

Comment: cheers that is cool stuff thanks for your help. it leaves me wondering about why socket.io has anything to do with an httpServer but I guess that's where I go read more things.

Comment: it also leaves me wondering about the advantages/disadvantages of binding to the same port as your primary httpServer ( using io.listen(server) )or creating a new one via new require('socket.io')()

Comment: Right. The "web" in web sockets means HTTP. socket.io can talk web sockets which runs over http initially then changes protocol to the websocket protocol, but it also works great over ajax HTTP long polling and a few other transports.

Comment: oh, I always assumed websockets were only TCP..but I don't know that much